# Having problem to switch between opened windows by using PyAutoGUI

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, automation, pyautogui

I am using `PyAutoGUI` to switch between the windows which I had opened.
Program runs successfully but not switching the windows.

Here's my code :

```
import pyautogui
import time
pyautogui.keyDown('alt')
pyautogui.press('tab')
time.sleep(1)
pyautogui.keyUp('alt')
```

Output :

```
program finished with exit code [0]
```

It runs but not switching the windows but when I did this manually it works.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `pyautogui.hotkey('alt', 'tab')` to press two buttons at once.

Comment: still not working in my computer

Comment: please give any other solution for this problem . i need it very much

Comment: Not sure why it wouldn't without more information.